# Analyzing a particular type of functions

Tags: functions

Let $f$ be a function from  $\mathbb{Z}$ to $ \mathbb{Z}$

Now $f(x)=x$

**Question**:

Is $f$ continuous in its domain?( perhaps yes by epsilon delta argument but I don't know if I am justified in doing so)

Is $f$ and other such functions (whose domain and co domain is a subset of real numbers) differentiable in its domain at all points?

How can we graph $f(x)$ and such other functions?

Comment: How do you define continuity or differentiability for functions defined on $\Bbb{Z}$? You need to be able to move in a neighborhood of a point $x_0$ to speak of differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

The function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ that sends $x\mapsto x$ is continuous. You can see this because any $\delta<1$ works for any $\epsilon$ at all, vacuously. Any any integer $a$, there is no $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $x\neq a$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(a)|>\epsilon$. That's what it would take to not be continuous.

You can also think about the more general, topological definition of continuity: a function is continuous if the pre-image of every open set is open. In this case, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a discrete set, so every subset it open. Therefore, any function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ (with the usual topology) is automatically continuous.

Graphing a function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is straightforward: it looks like a sequence of dots at lattice points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, as if a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ had all of its non-integer points erased.

As for your question about differentiability, I agree with the commenter above. It seems very odd to speak of differentiability without there being points arbitrarily close to each other. I believe the limit that we use to define the derivative of a function at a point would fail to exist because of non-uniqueness, although I'm not 100% certain of that.